# I am starting a new project with zend framework and would like some resources to help me

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am starting a new project with my new employer. I am used to developing applications in Ruby on Rails. The team I am working with are more orientated to PHP and have decided they would like to use Zend framework for our new project. I am already reasonably familiar with PHP but not Zend.

I am looking for any resources that may make my transition from Rails to Zend smooth. So any books, pod casts, videos or links that you would recommend would be very much appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Zend Framework](http://www.zendframework.com) site its self has a pretty good amount of literature that could help you out.

- [Quick Start](http://zendframework.com/docs/quickstart) (pretty good step-by-step guide to creating an application)
- [Videos](http://zendframework.com/docs/multimedia)
- [Documentation](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/) (lots of code samples)
- [Training](http://zendframework.com/services/training)

The [Zend Developer Zone](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend%20Framework) has some good articles on it.

[Steven Macintyre](http://steven.macintyre.name/category/technology/zend-framework/) has a good selection of articles written on the Zend Framework including a series on creating a CMS with it.

The [Zend Framework in Action](http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/) book and blog are both pretty good resources as well.

The [Beginning Zend Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218258) book isn't that bad either, but I'm not sure how out-dated it is since I know they've had a few releases in the past couple months.

The Zend Framework (like many OSS projects) tends to change pretty quickly so finding blogs and pod casts will probably be a little better, and safer, than buying a bunch of a books on it.

Answer (score 6):

There is a free electronic-book *(still a work in progress, and not finished yet ; but the first 9 or 10 chapters are there, and there are some nice ideas already)* called [Survive The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/)

*Disclaimer : I'm responsible for the french translation (not published yet) -- so I might be a bit biased.*

Comment: I have no reason to be biased and I can confirm this is a great resource :D

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at my free book for Zend Framework:

[Zend Framework: Surviving The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com)

The first 10 chapters are up online so far. It follows the development of a blog application in quite a bit of detail discussing Zend Framework features, issues met, and lots of information on melding all those components together with best practices.

Comment: thank you for writing such a valuable resource... you should get this published when it is finished!

Answer (score 4):

A ton of great videos can also be found at: http://www.zendcasts.com/

In addition my favorite forum for things ZF would be: http://www.zfforums.com/

Answer (score 3):

Rob Allen has written an excellent tutorial on getting started with ZF and he's also constantly updating it. You can find it here: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/